# Typescript console log and result in Postman different

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongoose, postman

I am new to NodeJS and TypeScript.

Need help and guidance on this.

Libs:

```
"@types/mongoose": "^5.11.97
"express": "^4.18.2",
"mongoose": "^6.7.0,
"@types/express": "^4.17.14",
"typescript": "^4.8.4"
```

I have 2 models

```
Artist.ts

export interface ArtistInput {
    name: string
}

export interface ArtistModel extends ArtistInput, Document {
    members: Array<MemberModel>
}

const artistSchema = new Schema(
    {
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true
        }
    }
);

artistSchema.virtual('members', {
    ref: 'Member',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'artist'
});

export default model<ArtistModel>('Artist', artistSchema);
```

```
Member.ts

interface MemberInput {
    name: string,
    birthdate?: Date
}

export interface MemberRequestPayload {
    artist: ArtistModel['_id'],
    members: MemberInput[]
}

export interface MemberModel extends MemberInput, Document {
}

const memberSchema = new Schema(
    {
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        birthdate: Date
        artist: {
            type: Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Artist',
            required: true,
        }
    }
);

export default model<MemberModel>('Member', memberSchema);
```

What happened was, when console log the result is below
[CONSOLE LOG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ax8b2.png)

but in the Postman result, it only returned the Artist data.
[POSTMAN RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pN6sM.png)

```
ArtistService.ts
export default async function get(artistId: string) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Artist.findById(artistId)
            .populate({
                path: 'members',
                select: 'name',
            })
            .exec((err, artist) => {
                console.log(artist);
                resolve(artist);
            });
    });
}
```

```
ArtistController.ts
try {
        return await getArtistService(artistId);
    } catch (e) {
        return message.error(res, e);
    }
```

What I expect is for the console.log result and result returned to Postman is same.

Please help me on this.

Any better code implementation is welcome too.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see the actual route handler with `req` and `res` parameters and how you call `res.json` or something like this to return the result to a client

Comment: The problem could be that the serialized object is not the same as the original one and that could be quite usual. Try to find something like `toJSON` along method of a model and compare the output with the one you got in the PostMan

Comment: turns out, I wrote `toJson`, it should be `toJSON`. Thanks @Anatoly. Appreciate with the help.